# Series in negative powers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, power-series

I want to find the asymptotic series of $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}, x>1$ in negative powers of $x$ while $x \to +\infty$, i.e. the sequence of coefficients $c_0, c_1, c_2, \dots$ such that $g(x) \sim c_0+\frac{c_1}{x}+\frac{c_2}{x^2}+\dots, x \to +\infty$

I have done the following:

We have that $\frac{1}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+\dots$, while $y \to 0^+$

So $g(x) \sim (-1) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$.

But how can we find an asymptic series in negative powers?

Comment: Note $\dfrac1{x-1}=\dfrac{1/x}{1-1/x}$

Comment: What you're looking for is called the Laurent series for $|x|>1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $$\frac 1{x-1}=\dfrac{\frac 1x}{1-\frac 1x}\\
=\frac 1x\left(1+\frac 1x+\frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1{x^3}\ldots\right)\\
=\frac 1x+\frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1{x^3}+\frac 1{x^4}\ldots$$
This converges for $|x| \gt 1$

Comment: Its clear to me now! Thank you! @RossMillikan